# Best statistical test to show significance of two data coming from the same population?

Tags: statistical-significance

Hope i'm posting in the right thread.

I have a sample of genes where I calculate a number of features in the start of each gene, and a number of features in the end of each gene. I plotted the results in 2 curves, one is the number of features in the start of each gene, and the other one is the number of features in the end of each gene, according to the position in the gene.
Now i'd like to know if the results I got are significant, knowing that the 2 curves come from the same population of genes (difference is the number of features is not calculated at the same location of the genes).
What would be the best statistical test to see if my results are significant?

Thanks in advance.

PS: I found this about standard errors. Do you think in my case, I could just use standard errors and if they don't overlap between the 2 curves, i can say my data are significant?
http://www.biochemia-medica.com/content/standard-error-meaning-and-interpretation

EDIT:
What i'd like to do is to show that i didn't get those curves by chance. The y axis represents the number of features and the x axis represents the position in the gene. I used the same sample of genes for the 2 measures plotted in the 2 different curves. Is there any test I can do to show that my results are good?

And here the corresponding curves of my results with the standard errors for each one of them:
[image]

Comment: "results" is too vague to be testable for significance. Different in terms of what? Also, what are the axes on your graph?

Comment: *Significance* is a term with a very [particular meaning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_significance) in statistics. "Data" are not of themselves "significant". Please edit to ask what you want to know in plain English terms, avoiding any statistical jargon at all. (Collectively, we're relatively good at interpreting plain English 'what I want to find out' requests into statistical ideas.)

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer, i will update now my question.

Comment: I just edited my question. Hope it's a bit more clear. Thanks.